# SearchOption.AllDirectories and ignore access errors?

Tags: list, search, recursive-datastructures

```
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(tb_dir.Text, tb_filter.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

I'm trying to search through a directory and all sub directory to find some file. I keep running into an error with the current code that the second it sees something it can't get into it breaks

In this application that doesn't matter i would rather it just move on. Is there anyway to bypass this code from dumping out everytime?

Thanks

Crash893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
List<string> GetFiles(string topDirectory, string filter)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(topDirectory, filter));
    foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(topDirectory))
    {
        list.AddRange(GetFiles(directory));
    }
    return list;
}
```

and call it with:

```
List<string> files = GetFiles(tb_dir.Text, tb_filter.Text);
```

You could convert the list of files into an array, of course.

You would have to add try catch blocks to handle the UnauthorizedAccessException.